# Channel entry: Slug from field pattern?

Tags: slug, entry-slug

I have defined an entry for a channel, let's say of persons, to have some fields, let's say `firstname`, `lastname` and `bio`, but no title.

When I created the first real entry, craft complained it had no slug. Apparently, that's drawn from the title.

I expected I could define the structure of the entry's slug to be pulled from any field, like `{firstname}-{lastname}`.

But I didn't find that option in the backend. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I found it: the option to enter the custom slug is displayed when you uncheck the Title.

And I set

```
    // don't accept umlauts for slugs
    'limitAutoSlugsToAscii' => true,
```

in the config.